# Accessing application variables in DataAccesslayer (another project under same solution)

Tags: ado.net, asp.net-3.5, application-variables

I have a solution with 3 projects.One of UI (contains web pages) and one for BL and one for DataAccess layer.Now i want to access one values stored in application variable in one class inside my DataAccess layer project.How can i access application variables there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the current [HTTPContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx) to the DAL.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend passing the value through your different layers.

You could probably use HttpContext.Current... to access it directly, but doing it that way would mean you now have a dependancy on Session state in your DAL, which will make testing and maintainance more awkward.

Comment: I agree, the data has to be extracted from HttpContext.Current and populate the business layer which handles the DAL. We don't want any dependancies between layers.